# Add a dynamic parameter to an angular2+ route

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

I have the following routes in my angular app:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/exercise-log', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'exercise-log/:date', component: ExerciseListComponent },
{ path: 'exercise-log', component: ExerciseListComponent }
```

I want to remove `exercise-log` and redirect `''` to the `'exercise-log/:date'` one and put today's date in instead.

How can I do this? I had thought about having a date variable that gets set in the constructor of the route module but that feels wrong.
UPDATE: trying to set it in a constructor doesn't seem to be the way having now tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply redirect it to `exercise-log/:date` with current time

```
{ path: 'exercise-log', redirectTo: '/exercise-log/' + Date.now(), pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Comment: Of course! This is my first from scratch angular project that I got wrapped up in the Angular of it all and missed the bleeding obvious!